# ¿Por qué no se dispara el evento onSelect en este código al seleccionar una fecha de un datepicker?

Tags: html, jquery-datepicker

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script>

function fmtFecha4(fecha){
  dia=fecha.getDate();
  mes=fecha.getMonth()+1; // porque los meses empiezan por 0
  anio=fecha.getFullYear();
  return dia+"/"+mes+"/"+anio;
 }  

 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
 $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
   closeText: 'Cerrar',
   prevText: '< Mes anterior',
   nextText: 'Mes Siguiente >',
   currentText: 'Hoy',
   monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
   monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
   dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
   dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Juv','Vie','Sab'],
   dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sa'],
   weekHeader: 'Sm',
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   firstDay: 1,
   isRTL: false,
   showMonthAfterYear: false,
   yearSuffix: '',
   showOtherMonths: true,
   selectOtherMonths: true,
   //showOn: "button",
   //Lo comentado es porque se utiliza CSS para poder el icono
   //buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
   //buttonImageOnly: true,
   buttonImage: "",
   buttonImageOnly: false,
   buttonText: ""
   
  };

 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);

 
  $("#fechamin").datepicker();
  $("#fechamax").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date()});
    
  
  $("#fechamin").datepicker( {
      onSelect: function(fecha) {
  console.log("select");  
      }  
  });
  
    $("#fechamax").datepicker( {
      maxDate: new Date()
  });
  
 
  $("#fechamin").on("change", function() {
  console.log("change");
    var fecha = $("#fechamin").datepicker("getDate");
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 30); 
    $("#fechamax").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
  
  });
  
  // Inicializar on un mes desde hoy
    var hoy = new Date();
    var hacedias = new Date();
 hacedias.setDate(hacedias.getDate() - 30);
   $("#fechamin").val(fmtFecha4(hacedias));
    $("#fechamax").val(fmtFecha4(hoy));
  
  
  $("#fechamax").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
      $(this).change();
    }
  }).on("change", function() {
    console.log("Change event");
  });
  
  
  
});
</script>

</head>
</body>
<input type="text" id="fechamin" />
<input type="text" id="fechamax" />



</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas sobre-escribiendo mucho el datepicker, solo tenías que agrupar las funciones.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script>

function fmtFecha4(fecha){
  dia=fecha.getDate();
  mes=fecha.getMonth()+1; // porque los meses empiezan por 0
  anio=fecha.getFullYear();
  return dia+"/"+mes+"/"+anio;
 }  

 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
 $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
   closeText: 'Cerrar',
   prevText: '< Mes anterior',
   nextText: 'Mes Siguiente >',
   currentText: 'Hoy',
   monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
   monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
   dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
   dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Juv','Vie','Sab'],
   dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sa'],
   weekHeader: 'Sm',
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   firstDay: 1,
   isRTL: false,
   showMonthAfterYear: false,
   yearSuffix: '',
   showOtherMonths: true,
   selectOtherMonths: true,
   //showOn: "button",
   //Lo comentado es porque se utiliza CSS para poder el icono
   //buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
   //buttonImageOnly: true,
   buttonImage: "",
   buttonImageOnly: false,
   buttonText: ""
   
  };

 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);

  $("#fechamax").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
      $(this).change();
    },
    maxDate: new Date()
  }).on("change", function() {
    console.log("Change event");
  });

  $("#fechamin").datepicker( {
      onSelect: function(fecha) {
          console.log("select min");  
      }
  }).on("change", function() {
    console.log("change");
    var fecha = $("#fechamin").datepicker("getDate");
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 30); 
    $("#fechamax").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
  });
  
     // Inicializar on un mes desde hoy
    var hoy = new Date();
    var hacedias = new Date();
 hacedias.setDate(hacedias.getDate() - 30);
   $("#fechamin").val(fmtFecha4(hacedias));
    $("#fechamax").val(fmtFecha4(hoy));

});
</script>

</head>
</body>
<input type="text" id="fechamin" />
<input type="text" id="fechamax" />



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma funcionarina los onSelect, pero los onChange dejan de funcionar, por eso los he borrado.

```html
<html>

  <head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script>
  function fmtFecha4(fecha) {
    dia = fecha.getDate();
    mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1; // porque los meses empiezan por 0
    anio = fecha.getFullYear();
    return dia + "/" + mes + "/" + anio;
  }


  $(document).ready(function() {

    $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
      closeText: 'Cerrar',
      prevText: '< Mes anterior',
      nextText: 'Mes Siguiente >',
      currentText: 'Hoy',
      monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
      monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
      dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
      dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
      dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
      weekHeader: 'Sm',
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      firstDay: 1,
      isRTL: false,
      showMonthAfterYear: false,
      yearSuffix: '',
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      //showOn: "button",
      //Lo comentado es porque se utiliza CSS para poder el icono
      //buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
      //buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonImage: "",
      buttonImageOnly: false,
      buttonText: ""

    };

    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);


    $("#fechamin").datepicker({
      onSelect: function(fecha) {
        console.log("select");
      }
    });

    $("#fechamax").datepicker({
      maxDate: new Date(),
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
        console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
        $(this).change();
      }
    });



    $("#fechamax").datepicker({
      maxDate: new Date()
    });


    // Inicializar on un mes desde hoy
    var hoy = new Date();
    var hacedias = new Date();
    hacedias.setDate(hacedias.getDate() - 30);
    $("#fechamin").val(fmtFecha4(hacedias));
    $("#fechamax").val(fmtFecha4(hoy));
  });

</script>

  </head>
  </body>
  <input type="text" id="fechamin" />
  <input type="text" id="fechamax" />



  </body>
```